# Return Json on a bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

So OK(value) returns formatted json with an application/json header. However the BadRequest() does not. If the request is a application/json shouldn't the response be like that even if it's a bad request?

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Resolution value)
{
    using (_ctx)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ValidateResolution(value.Size))
            {
                _ctx.Resolution.Add(value);
                _ctx.SaveChanges();
                return Ok(value);
            }
            return BadRequest("{ \"message\": \"hello\" }");
        } catch (Exception) {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What you're doing is passing a string to `BadRequest()` which makes your Action return a response with a content-type of plain text.

If you'd like to return a JSON object with a response type of `application/json`, then you should pass an object that isn't a string to `BadRequest()`. You can even pass an anonymous object to quickly create a JSON object like so:

```cs
return BadRequest(new { message = "bad request"});
```

PS: The proper JSON format is `{"field_name" : "field_value"}` (quotation marks are not necessary for the value if its type is number, bool, null). So from what you've written, even if you changed the content-type to `application/json`, it could not be properly parsed.

Comment: Thank you!  Ah, yes, that JSON wasn't proper.  I just threw that together for this example.

Comment: How can this work? Ok method is generic and accepts any object, but BadRequest is not generic and thus I get "cannot convert from anonymous type to string" when trying to send anonymous object

Comment: BadRequest can take an object as a parameter:
[see image](https://i.imgur.com/HfnY95y.png)

Comment: not working for me, I can only put pure string as an argument, but the again it's not Json format so I don't know what else to do