# How to return BadRequest response with custom error model? WEB API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, webapi2

I want to return below json with BadRequest

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
        "description": "frId is/are not required and should not be sent",
        "source": null,
        "step": null,
        "reason": null,
        "metadata": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/jasontaylordev/NorthwindTraders/blob/master/Src/WebUI/Common/CustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291834/return-json-on-a-bad-request

Answer (score -1):

You can make a class to encapsulate the response object like this:

```
class Error
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Step { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public object Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can return a instance of that object like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SomeGetReq()
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(someService.SomeMethod());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // you can use e here
        return BadRequest(new Error
        {
            Code = "BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
            Description = "frId is/are not required and should not be sent"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: BadRequest() constructor accepts string format...its not accepting class object.. :/

Comment: Make sure your function returns [IActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1#:~:text=IActionResult%20type,represent%20various%20HTTP%20status%20codes.&text=Alternatively%2C%20convenience%20methods%20in%20the,ActionResult%20types%20from%20an%20action.)